# Read the contents of html file AS html not as text

Tags: html, ruby-on-rails-4, nokogiri

This is probably a dumb question... I'm loading up an HTML file with HTML markup that I want to be executed in the view, but currently it's just showing me text.

**View code:**
    <%= @parsed_protip %>

**Controller code for the view:**

```
def show
    protip = File.read(File.join("app/assets/protips/" + params[:id] + ".html.erb"))
    @parsed_protip = Nokogiri::HTML(protip)
end
```

I need the view to render all the HTML in the file, for example, the file might look like this:

```
<title>Some title</title>
<div class="row">
   <%= image_tag "..." %>
</div>
<div class="row">
   <p>asdfasdf</p>
</div>
```

But the output I'm getting is basically this in one big text paragraph:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40/loose.dtd"> <html> <head> <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"> <title>Should you buy or rent gear?</title> <meta name="description" content="Interactive calculator to help you figure out whether you should rent or buy your own gear"> </head> <body> <div class="row"> </div> <div class="row"> <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-8"> <div class="col-xs-8 col-xs-offset-2"> <h1>Should you buy your own snowsports apparel?</h1> <p>Your friend invited you to Tahoe this weekend. You’ve never skied before and you’re excited for the sheer adrenaline rush of flying down some slopes. You leave work early on Thursday to pick up some a...
```

Comment: Try `<%= @parsed_protip.html_safe %>`

Comment: Ok so html_safe works without Nokogiri, but the problem is that the ruby doesn't evaluate. Anyway to get that to work? Or should I just convert the Ruby to straight HTML?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, `Nokogiri::HTML` parses the text to a `Nokogiri::HTML` object not to HTML as you need it.

Instead, convert all the Ruby code on the file you want to parse to plain HTML. Then use `html_safe` to convert the text to valid HTML.

Comment: Got it, the challenge though is that the ERB doesn't evaluate. Is there a way to do that?

Comment: ERB markup is not valid HTML, so no, it can't be evaluated by a HTML parser.